# `tail -qf *.log`, except pick up new files too

Tags: linux, debian, tail

I have multiple processes doing some computation; they routinely come and go, and often work in parallel. I'd like to have a single `tmux` window following their logs—all of them together.

I've tried using `tail -qf *.log`, but I need to restart it often, as it does not notice new files.

I've also tried `multitail -Iw '*.log' 10`, but it doesn't seem to follow all files, just the one most recently changed.

Is there any tool that would be an equivalent of `tail -qf`, but also follow new files as they are created?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk, indeed it seems it does. I must have missed this question when searching for my solution. Feel free to mark it as a duplicate.